# Showing asymptotic stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that $\tilde x=0$ is asymptotically stable for

$x'=-t \cos x, t \in \mathbb R$

I guess I need to find a Lyapunov function but I'm not sure

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: These posts may help: [Lyapunov stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108864/lyapunov-stability/2287052#2287052), [Finding Lyapunov Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226400/finding-lyapunov-function/2227147#2227147), [How to find out a suitable Lyapunov function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280096/how-to-find-out-a-suitable-lyapunov-function/2280109#2280109), [Finding a Lyapunov function for a given system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297904/finding-a-lyapunov-function-for-a-given-system/2278563#2278563).

Comment: Or this: [Using a Lyapunov function to classify stability and sketching a phase portrait
](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204990/using-a-lyapunov-function-to-classify-stability-and-sketching-a-phase-portrait/3205002#3205002)

Comment: One problem with this question is that $0$ is not an equilibrium for $\dot x = -t\cos x$ for all $t$; on the other hand, if we consider $\dot x = -t \sin x$ . . . or look at the equilibria $x = (2n + 1)\pi / 2$

Comment: @RobertLewis How would it work for $x'=-t \sin x$?

Comment: @user679927:  give me a little while and I'll see what I can come up with.  Cheers!

Comment: @user679927:  still at it; got a bit distracted!;)